# How To Terminate a One-Liner CMD "DO" Command (REVISED)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following line of CMD code (not batch):

```
for /l %A in (1,1,2) do (echo "in loop") & echo "out loop; this should only be echoed once"
```

Basically, those brackets (at least I thought) is what were supposed to end the loop code and start a new command OUTSIDE of the `do` command; however that doesn't seem to be happening.

If someone could tell me how to terminate the `do` statement to execute the last `echo` command individually after the loop instead of on each iteration of the loop while still keeping it a one-liner, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `(for /l %A in (1,1,2) do (echo "in loop") )& echo "out loop; this should only be echoed once"`

Comment: @penknife Thank you so much! Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire **FOR** command line must be enclosed in parenthesis and then the additional **ECHO** command can be appended with operator `&` to be executed unconditionally after the **FOR** loop.

Command line:

```
(for /L %A in (1,1,2) do @echo in loop) & @echo out loop; this should only be echoed once
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off
(for /L %%A in (1,1,2) do echo in loop) & echo out loop; this should only be echoed once
```

The single command `echo in loop` executed by `for` does not need to be enclosed in parenthesis.

See also [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Comment: Thanks for your succinct answer. The `@` before the `echo` makes the output cleaner in CMD as well, which is something I was unaware of.